# Query label_values not found in Prometheus

Tags: grafana, prometheus, promql

In the Grafana documentation, I found that I should be able to query my Prometheus server for all instances delivering monitoring data using the `label_values` query.

The query I'm using in Grafana is:

```
label_values(up, instance)
```

Unfortunately, Prometheus tells me that it is not aware of label_values:

```sh
Error executing query: parse error at char 13: unknown function with name "label_values"
```

I am using Prometheus 2.0.0 and Grafana 5.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: label_values is not prometheus function, it is part of grafana templating.

Answer (score 32):

`label_values()` is only a valid function within [templating](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/datasources/prometheus/#templating). You can use it to populate a template dropdown with e.g. a list of available instances or available metrics but you can't use it within a dashboard or when querying Prometheus directly.

Comment: Okay. Despite having multiple instances shown in e.x an up query the label_values() does not fill my dropdown in grafana. Any idea

Comment: I am getting \<error expanding template: error executing template ... at \<query>: error calling query: parse error at char 13: unknown function with name "label_values"> in Prometheus templating, this is not works in Prometheus... This works only in Grafana.

Answer (score 13):

By looking into Grafana's template code for Prometheus in [grafana/public/app/plugins/datasource/prometheus/metric_find_query.ts](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/ce8df91cc9574eec9c7e6f12e5cc4bb6322e20dc/public/app/plugins/datasource/prometheus/metric_find_query.ts) you can see that they do not use PromQL, but visit certain endponts to the get the label values, so for `label_values(instance)` the URL would be something like this:

```
http://localhost:9090/api/v1/label/instance/values
```

This one however returns all labels called `instance` from every metric in the TSDB. If the label is unique for one particular metric, then you have your answer. Otherwise the template code for something like `label_values(up, instance)` it is slightly more complicated and it seems like it actually downloads the whole series for the metric from:

```
http://localhost:9090/api/v1/series?match[]=up
```

also adding time range parameters `start` and `end` which I omitted for clarity, then finds the label values by parsing the JSON output.

I would also like to do the same in PromQL, but I have not figured out whether it is possible or not.

Comment: thank you for the reference to the label api! this info was missing in the accepted answer

Answer (score -4):

`labels(pg_up,instances)` this is correct syntax

Comment: there's nothing wrong with syntax