# Grafana state timeline panel with values (states) supplied by label

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I do have a Prometheus time series with samples like these:

```
a_metric{band="1", state="A"} 1
a_metric{band="2", state="C"} 1
a_metric{band="1", state="A"} 1
a_metric{band="2", state="C"} 1
a_metric{band="1", state="B"} 1
a_metric{band="1", state="B"} 1
...
```

I would like to visualize this time series in a [state timeline](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/visualizations/state-timeline/) panel such that `band`s become horizontal bands and `state`s become discrete states within these bands. For this, I would have to extract values from the label `state` (and use them instead of values 1).

Is this possible and can such a visualization be achieved?

If I understand correctly Prometheus' [`label_values()`](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/) cannot serve here, because it is restricted to [templating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49365793/query-label-values-not-found-in-prometheus). I suspect Grafana transformations could play a role, but I do not yet have experience with those. The complication also arises because Prometheus does not have [string type metrics](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/2227).

**UPDATE** Here is a basic image, as requested by @JanGaray.

[image: basic image]

Comment: I would add basic image to the question, because I'm not sure what do you want to achieve.

Comment: The link to state_timeline shows me empty page. What works for me is https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/next/visualizations/state-timeline/

Comment: @JanVlcinsky Weird. The link in the post redirects to your URL when I open it.

Answer (score 36):

> suspect Grafana transformations could play a role

It is indeed possible with transformations.

### In short

1. Set query format to `table`
2. Add transformation `Grouping to matrix`.

   - Set column to `band`
   - Set row to `time`
   - Set cell_value to `state`
3. Add transformation `Convert field type`

   - Set field to `Time/<column>`
   - As `Time`
4. Configure `Value mappings` for each of the states you have

### Explanation

I'll show how the transformations work
To see what is happening in the transformations, it is always helpful to enable the [image: Table view toggle set to active] as this will show actual returned data to the visualization.
Also toggling the transformations on and off using the [image: symbol of an eye] next to transformation really helps in seeing what is happening.

The state timeline visualization works best with a table as data source.
Although it does support time series, the information we want to show is not a time series.

The visualization works best when the data is as follows.

| Time | Band 1 | Band 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | State A | State B |
| T2 | State C | State A |

But when data is formatted as a time series the data will look like this:

| Time | {Band 1, State A} | {Band 1, State C} | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | 1 |  |  |
| T2 |  | 1 |  |

---

So first we need to set query format to from `Timeseries` to `Table`.
Expend the query options, and set format to `Table.`

When doing that our table will look like this.

| Time | band | state | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | Band 1 | State A | 1 |
| T1 | Band 2 | State B | 1 |
| T2 | Band 1 | State C | 1 |
| T2 | Band 1 | State A | 1 |

---

Next step is to pivot the table. For this we add the `Grouping to matrix` transformation.

- Set column to `band`
- Set row to `time`
- Set cell_value to `state`

| Time | Band 1 | Band 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | State A | State B |
| 2000 | State C | State A |

---

Now there is just one problem left. The first column should be of data type `time` but it is of type `string`. You can see this by the icon infront of the column name. Indicated with emoji in my examples.

But this is an easy fix. Just add `Convert field type` transformation below `Grouping to matrix` transformation.

- Set field to `Time/<column>`
- As `Time`

Now the table should look as follows:

| Time | Band 1 | Band 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | State A | State B |
| T2 | State C | State A |

### Example

Following shows an example for ArgoCD.
It shows the sync status for each application over time.

The prometheus exported data from ArgoCD looks as follows:

```
argocd_app_info{name="Application A", sync_state="Synced", ...} 1
argocd_app_info{name="Application B", sync_state="OufOfSync", ...} 1
argocd_app_info{name="Application C", sync_state="Unknown", ...} 1
argocd_app_info{name="Application D", sync_state="Synced", ...} 1
```

[image: State timeline visualization example]

Comment: Note: The Transformation `Grouping to matrix` is available in Grafana 8.5 or higher.

Comment: As a follow-up, in the event of spotty data, you might need to additionally apply a "Sort by" transformation on your `Time/<column>` field.

Comment: @Waaghals Do you know if it is still possible to show additional information in a tooltip? E.g. in the above example the column `value` should be shown in the tooltip. I can not think of a solution because that column is removed by the `Grouping to matrix` transformation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible since as you said prometheus is not designed to use strings as values. If you have control over the exporter that is giving you these metrics, you can change the states to different values without the state label, and then use Value Mappings to map: 1 == State A; 2 == State B; etc

Surfacing it this way also will remove the issue of a given `band` being in multiple states at a given time. Storing the states as labels means your app needs to turn off a given label/state in addition to turning on the next state. If you forget to do this, then the metric will show the `band` in 2 states at once.

For the blackbox exporter, we get metrics like below with the query `probe_success`. This can only be 1/0 but the example would work if you have more states as well.

```
probe_success{instance="https://app1.example.com", job="blackbox"}  0
probe_success{instance="https://app2.example.com", job="blackbox"}  0
probe_success{instance="https://app3.example.com", job="blackbox"}  1
probe_success{instance="https://app4.example.com", job="blackbox"}  1
```

Set the Value Mappings to map from the number to string

[image: simple value mappings]

[image: stat timeline viz]

Comment: The prometheus [training](https://training.robustperception.io/courses/205011/lectures/3157135) resource suggests using labels to report string metrics. I feel like there must be some way to *use* such metrics? @brian-brazil am I misunderstanding your instruction in the linked page?

Comment: The trouble is that in my case there is an open set of states, so coming up with a mapping up-front is impossible. I know that Prometheus is not designed to use strings as values, but I though perhaps Grafana could use a designated label (its value being a string) instead of actual values from Prometheus (which are constant at 1.0 in this case). This could allow it to accomplish with the Prometheus datasource what is possible with other ones. Does not seem to be the case, though.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do with https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/flant-statusmap-panel/

It has exactly same case in the description, and I used it to show statuses of the consul services exported with the consul exporter where the status goes to the `status` label.