# Randomize state timeline color by state name

Tags: grafana

I'm trying to visualize k8s pod lifetimes on their respective nodes as deployments occur. By following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72515955/8916171), I've been able to get the layout I'm looking for:

[image: current grafana panel]

However, all the pod lifetimes for one node (one entire row) are the same color, until one hovers the mouse cursor over the graph - I'd like these to be different colors, so that it's easier to see the delineations at-a-glance.

Usually this would be done with Value Mappings - but in this case, the value names are randomly generated, and I can't possibly add mappings for all of them beforehand. I'd like Grafana to hash the value (string) to dynamically map that to a color - is there any way to do something like that?

Comment: Same issue here - I have (currently) 92 possible values that are partly nested. Your solution unfortunately is not applicable to my case. But thanks anyway for your effort!

Comment: @akrea Grafana has a JSON representation for dashboards - presumably, you could see what JSON fields are added for the Value Mappings, and then programmatically generate the mappings and upload/import the resulting JSON into grafana, instead of creating them all by hand via the GUI - as long as the 92 values are statically known

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: In addition to the solution below for coloring, it can be useful to raise the `Line width` attribute on the `State Timeline` properties to show transition boundaries more clearly when successive elements are the same color, which can reduce the need for different coloring.

---

Turns out, it is possible to have Value Mappings that are regex-based - for this example, the random strings can be bucketed by a prefix, with a color assigned to each bucket. The random portion obeys the alphabet `[a-z0-9]`, for a total of 36 characters. I created 18 regex-based Value mappings, each covering random strings that start with one of two characters (this is only slightly tedious):

[image: regex value mappings]

This is the result:

[image: result]

*side note: For this usecase, it was also helpful to create a `Special` value mapping to match `Empty` and color it `Transparent`, to draw the gaps when there was no pod on a particular node.*

To create a regex value mapping, click the `Add a new mapping` button in the `Value mappings` dialog:

[image: regex mapping howto 1]

and then pick `Regex`

[image: regex mapping howto 2]